# How to continue executing stored procedure after exception in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am running a stored procedure to full a new table with random records from another table. However, the target table as PK to avoid duplicate values. Therefore, the stored procedure stops when finding duplicate entry. How can I continue the execution without executing manually from the command line every time that it stops?

mysql> call random_while();
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1039499' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `random_while`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5500;
  /*DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062 go to label continue;*/

  /*label:label continue;*/
  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    INSERT INTO `random_pull_request`
    SELECT t2.* FROM (SELECT name FROM project_pull_request ppr, 
                                  (SELECT RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id_project)-1 
                                   FROM project_pull_request) AS tid) AS tmp
                                   WHERE ppr.id_project >= tmp.tid
                                   ORDER BY id_project ASC
                                   LIMIT 1) AS id_random_project, pull_request_class_merged t2
    WHERE id_random_project.name = t2.project_name  
    order by rand() LIMIT 1;
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Thank you for your help.

Kind Regards

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very good design to be honest, because as you get more and more records in the table, you'll have to use more and more "guesses" before you find a valid value.

Comment: I have continued searching I applied IGNORE to insert into statement and now it's working. Thank you